# Can I get the 'line breaks' in a contenteditable div-tag that's word-wrapping?

Tags: javascript, nicedit

I'm using nicedit, which uses a contenteditable DIV-tag as input field, on a page where a user can enter and format some text, which then is submitted to a php-script which converts this formatted text into an image.
The text in this contenteditable div is getting word-wrapped with no line-break characters where it is wrapped. 
Is there any way to find out where this wrapping occurred, or insert line-breaks when occurrs, so that I can access the text as separate lines?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to calculate the pixel co-ordinates of each word, which is possible but non-trivial to achieve cross-browser. One way would be to insert a zero-width dummy element before each word and use its position. Recent WebKit and Firefox browsers give you a [`getClientRects()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/range.getClientRects) method of DOM Range objects, which is preferable as it is less invasive and likely performs better. IE's proprietary `TextRange` objects have methods to move between words and properties `boundingLeft` and [`boundingTop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that will give you the bounding box of the TextRange.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach, change the way you're rendering that image. Perhaps you can find a graphics library that handles word wrapping automatically, or replicate the HTML on the page and take a snapshot using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or similar.